# bug in vim editing, caused by tab or diacritics?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I have the following line in a file (notice the tab in the beginning):

```
    $q = "select pl.id, pl.pltag tag, tf.nome família, tg.nome Gênero, ts.nome espécie, l.nome localidade
```

When I try to edit it, let's say, replace Gênero with gênero, I move the cursor up to "G", change Insert to Replace (pressing the insert key again), and then typing "g" over it. It looks like it worked, but when I quit and save, I find that the file now has:

```
tg.nomeGgênero
```

Looks like the first tab is confusing Vim? Or perhaps the diacritics used in Portuguese language (accepted by Postgresql)? I'm using terminal in Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, connected through ssh to another machine with Ubuntu Server 14.04, where I'm editing the file.

Although Vim doesn't say anything about locale, psql says the following:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Perhaps `LC_ALL = (unset)` is the source of the problem?

The output from `stty -a`, as requested in the comments:

(my machine)

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

(server)

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Comment: I would suspect rather terminal settings. can you post `stty -a` ? I no longer have a ubuntu, but i will compare with my tumbleweed setting. Also, have you set locale ?

Comment: "stty -a" from my machine or from the server? When sshed in the server, vim doesn't complain about locale, though psql does. I'll add the locale settings to my question, as shown in the message from psql.

Comment: Stty from both. I had similar problem with putty (obviously not yhe case here).

Comment: Edited the question with both stty, @Archemar.

Comment: Try toggling iutf8.

Comment: How do I do that?